# RunWait() - add parameters

Tags: autoit, execute

My AutoIt script launches another script (written in UIAutomation). So I wrote this:

```
RunWait("C:\AutoUIInst\Test\bin\Debug\" & "Test.exe", "","")
```

It works fine. But now I have to add a parameter. For example: `"Test.exe -someParam"` . So i tried [`RunWait()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/RunWait.htm) :

```
RunWait('"C:\AutoUIInst\Test\bin\Debug\" & "Test.exe" -someParam', "","")
```

That won't work. Can someone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe there is only a space missing right before the paramter.

```
RunWait("C:\AutoUIInst\Test\bin\Debug\Test.exe -someParam", "","")
```

You can also try ShellexecuteWait which also has a Parameter option!

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problems some time ago when running another applications from my script and I solved it by using [`ShellExecuteWait`](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ShellExecuteWait.htm). You can rewrite your call like this:

`ShellExecuteWait("C:\AutoUIInst\Test\bin\Debug\Test.exe", "-someParam")`

Comment: This also works  fine, thanks a lot for answering.
What is the difference between this command and one use by Xenobiologist?

Comment: Run can be used to start exe files and to get the process ID backand you can read and write to Stdin/"Stdout"/Stderr- this can be important for communication between processes and programs. Shellexecute can start or open files. It "starts/opens" the files with the programs associated to the extension.